# How to define one-to-many connection between a same model through another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to define one-to-many relationship as follows;

- User has one introducer
- User has many newcomers(who is introduced by the user)
- Use "Introduction" model instead of adding a column to users table.

My table and model definition is as follows;

DB Scheme:

```
create_table "introductions", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "introducer_id"
  t.integer "newcomer_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :introductions, foreign_key: :introducer_id
  has_many :newcomers, through: :introductions, source: :newcomer
  belongs_to :introduction, foreign_key: :newcomer_id 
  belongs_to :introducer 
end
```

Introduction model:

```
class Introduction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :introducer, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :newcomer, class_name: 'User'  
end
```

This works fine:

```
user1.newcomers.push user2
```

but,

```
user2.introducer
# => nil
```

How can I define belongs_to relationship correctly?

Comment: `belongs_to :introducer` in your `User` model should be `belongs_to :introducer, class_name: 'User'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I think should have used `has_one` instead of `belongs_to`.

then, thanks to @Paven, my solution becomes,

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :introductions, foreign_key: :introducer_id 
  has_many :newcomers, through: :introductions, source: :newcomer

  has_one :introduction, foreign_key: :newcomer_id
  has_one :introducer, through: :introduction, class_name: 'User'
end
```